# Remove element from Kubernetes object array with Argo Events

Tags: kubernetes, events, amazon-sqs, argo, argo-events

I have following `Argo Events` manifest with `Sensor` configuration that consume messages from `AWS SQS` message queue.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: aws-sqs
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: admin-user
  replicas: 1
  dependencies:
    - name: test-name
      eventSourceName: aws-sqs
      eventName: example
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: create-deployment
        k8s:
          operation: create
          patchStrategy: "application/strategic-merge-patch+json"
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: apps/v1
              kind: Deployment
              metadata:
                name: nginx-deployment
                labels:
                  app: nginx
              spec:
                replicas: 1
                selector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: nginx
                template:
                  metadata:
                    labels:
                      app: nginx
                  spec:
                    containers:
                    - name: nginx
                      image: nginx:1.14.2
                      ports:
                      - containerPort: 80
          parameters:
            - src:
                dependencyName: test-name
                dataTemplate: "{{ .Input.body.name | lower }}"
              dest: spec.template.spec.containers.0.nameam
```

Base on message body I am able to append new elements to `containers` list and add as many containers as I would like to.

Problem start when I am trying to do the opposite since I don't know how to remove element from array with `Argo Events`.

My desire scenario is to send message on different `AWS SQS` queue with container `name` and `Argo Events` sensor will remove only container mentioned by `name` in queue.

Is this even possible natively in `Argo Events` or I will need to create custom application that will do the job and configure webhook endpoint that will be triggered when new message arrive to queue?